# Jquery after load link, scroll to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently using bootsrap.

I have a main navigation menu.

I am linking each section on the main nav drop down menu to another page with a specific ID, which is a set of tabs on another page.

(Visual Composer Tabs - Wordpress)

The hash change function below shows the top of the page for a second however it then still scrolls to the hash...

**Update HashChange Not Working**

```
  $(window).on('hashchange',function(e){
  document.body.scrollTop = 0; 
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

**UPDATE - JQUERY NOT WORKING**

```
 $('.link-2').click(function() {    
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#1234567891011").offset().top }); 
 });
```

I am linking it directly this way so that the tab appears as active when the link is clicked.

My code is below.

```html
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="http://myURL#123456789">Title<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a class="link-2" href="http://myURL#1234567891011">Tab Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="link-3" href="http://myURL#1234567891011">Tab Link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

The problem is when the link is opened it automatically goes to that tab section with that ID, which cuts out half of the information before the tabs.

I need it to load at the top of the page but still keep the tab active. How can i do this with Jquery?

Comment: You mean you want your page to scroll to the top page every time you click a link in the tab?

Comment: I want the page to scroll to the top on the next page once the link-2 or link-3 class has been clicked.

Comment: You can use `$('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#YOUR_DIV_ID").offset().top
});` once you click the link in the tab

Comment: I have updated the Jquery but it still doesnt work. I basically just dont want it to scroll to the hash and just load the page like normal.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: To make it easy for us to help you fix your problem, in your code snippet, can you add more code so we can easily replicate your issue?

Comment: so... as @prtdomingo mentioned - you should use **$("#1234567891011")** in order to solve your problem.. let's move on people :)

Comment: @ymz that actually doesnt work, yeah i know i missed the # in the update

Answer (score 0):

Alter your hash not to trigger the scroll

Change your hash to: #tab_1234567891011
in the page you want to navigate get the id of the tab by splitting this hash

```
id = window.location.hash.split('_')[1];
```

activate the tab with the new id:

```
$('#'+id).tab('show');
```

Comment: when you arrive on a page with a hash you trigger the hashchange event

Comment: prevent that event and the page doesn't scroll to your hash

Comment: I see, thats exactly what i need, but the code above does still scroll to the hash